# How do I store my ObjectResults to a POCO?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

This question is probably most trivial to most but I am just getting started with EF 4 and can't seem to assign my results from a stored procedure to my object.   Is this possible?

```
List<GetRotationSummary_Result> currentPD;
RotationData myData = new RotationData();

currentPD = context.GetData(compId, roleId, email).ToList()
MyData = currentPD;  // Can this even be done???
```

I want to store the data in the MyData object since users will have the ability to change the data.  After which I would like to update the database.    Completely open to any suggestions.   Many thanks.

Comment: You haven't show the declaration of `MyData`.  What is it?  If you meant `myData` instead, then what would you expect to happen when trying to set something of type `List<GetRotationSummary_Reslt>` to a `RotationData` variable?  How might that conversion take place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't directly assign the objects like that since they are completely different types. You would need to create a function to do a field-by-field assignment of properties from `currentPD` to `myData`.  A tool like [automapper](http://automapper.org/) can make this much easier.